# Integral of familly of curves

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f_n(t):=t^{n+m+1/3}e^{-(t^{-n}+t^{-m}+t^2)}$, where $n,m\geq 1$.  I have been having difficulty calculating this ingetral on $\mathbb{R}$.  Please help, thanks.

Comment: The integral is not convergent over $\mathbb{R}$. As $t \to \infty$, the integrand is greater than $e^{t^2}$.

Comment: Sorry I was missing a negation, it's there now; Thanks for pointing that out.